# How to compare dataframes with the same size but different information

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames where each row is a product and each column is a different month,they always have the same size and are something like this:

```
data1 = {
    "product": ['A', "B", "C", "D"],
    "2022-01": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "2022-02": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "2022-03": [1, 2, 3, 4]
}

data2 = {
    "product": ['A', "B", "C", "D"],
    "2022-01": [13, "None", 15, 16],
    "2022-02": [17, 18, "None", 20],
    "2022-03": ["None", 22, 23, "None"]
}
```

The difference between them is that the second one can sometimes contain `None` values. I would like to first create a third dataframe with the interleaved data, like this (The flag would be to indicate that it was inserted):

```
data3 = {
    "product": ['A', "B", "C", "D"],
    "2022-01": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "2022-01 - flag": [13, "None", 15, 16],
    "2022-02": [5, 6, 7, 8],
    "2022-02 - flag": [17, 18, "None", 20],
    "2022-03": [9, 10, 11, 12]
    "2022-03 - flag": ["None", 22, 23, "None"]
}
```

And also another dataframe where I'm going to put the `None` values from `data2` and put them in `data1`. Basically I think I need to iterate over the columns of dataframes 1 and 2 based on dates (since they have the same product) but I don't know how to do that properly. The final dataframe of this would look something like this:

```
data4 = {
    "product": ['A', "B", "C", "D"],
    "2022-01": [1, "None", 3, 4],
    "2022-02": [5, 6, "None", 8],
    "2022-03": ["None", 10, 11, "None"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`pandas.DataFrame.mask`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) to get directly the output you're looking for:

```
df1= pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2= pd.DataFrame(data2)

out = df1.mask(df2.replace("None", None).isna())
#out = df1.mask(df2.eq("None")) --- another alternative
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)

  product  2022-01  2022-02  2022-03
0       A      1.0      5.0      NaN
1       B      NaN      6.0     10.0
2       C      3.0      NaN     11.0
3       D      4.0      8.0      NaN
```